# Is it possible to have two different DataContext in one UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

Is it possible to have two different `DataContext` in one UserControl? I would like to access one of my `Model` objects, but also properties in the MainViewModel. Examples:

ClassDatas `DataContext` (an object defined in a Model):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="PropertiesControl1" Height="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding ClassDatas}" HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Fields}" Header="" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

MainViewModel `DataContext`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtFields" Text="{Binding FieldsTextProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Background="#FFCBEECD" AcceptsReturn="False" >.....</TextBox>
```

And further how is it possible to combine them?

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtFields" Text="{Binding FieldsTextProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Background="#FFCBEECD" AcceptsReturn="False" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <iex:KeyTrigger Key="Enter">              
                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.AddFieldCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                    </iex:KeyTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

The `FieldsTextProperty` is a `DataContext` from the `MainViewModel` and the `EventToCommand` contains `DataContext` from my object.

Comment: [C# using 2 different DataContext](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+using+2+different+DataContext&oq=C%23+using+2+different+DataContext&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.13639j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2):

No, a control can only have a single object set to its `DataContext` property

However a binding doesn't *have* to bind to it's `DataContext`. You can use other binding properties to specify a different source for the binding. Commonly used properties to change the source for a binding are `Source`, `RelativeSource`, and `ElementName`.

- You can either change the binding's source for a specific binding only, such as you're doing in your `Command` binding
- Or you can change it for an entire control by setting or binding the control's `DataContext` property to something else

I actually see so much confusion over the `DataContext` in WPF beginners that I wrote a blog post about it. You may be interested in reading it over : [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)

Here's a code block I use to help demonstrate the `DataContext`:

> Suppose we bind a window to an object called `ClassA`. `ClassA` has a property called `ClassB`, and both `ClassA` and `ClassB` have a property called `Name`.
>
> Here is a block of XAML which illustrates how the DataContext works. It also includes an example of how a control would refer to a property not in its own DataContext.

```
public partial class MyWindow: Window
{
    public MyWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = new ClassA();
    }
}

public class ClassA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```xml
<!-- DataContext set to ClassA in initialization code -->
<Window x:Name="MyWindow"> 
 
    <!-- DataContext here is not specified, so it's inherited 
         from its parent's DataContext, which is ClassA -->
    <StackPanel> 
 
        <!-- DataContext inherited from parent, which is 
             ClassA, so this will display ClassA.Name -->
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
 
         <!-- DataContext is still ClassA, however we are 
              setting it to ClassA.ClassB with a binding -->
        <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ClassB}">
 
            <!-- DataContext inherited from parent, which is 
                 ClassB, so this will display ClassB.Name -->
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
 
            <!-- DataContext is still ClassB, but we are 
                 binding to the Window's DataContext.Name, 
                 which is ClassA.Name -->
            <Label Content="{Binding 
                       ElementName=MyWindow, 
                       Path=DataContext.Name}" /> 
        </StackPanel>
 
        <!-- We've left the StackPanel with its DataContext 
             bound to ClassB, so this Label's DataContext 
             is ClassA (inherited from parent StackPanel), 
             and we are binding to ClassA.ClassB.Name -->
        <Label Content="{Binding ClassB.Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: So if I use `Text="{Binding MainViewModel.FieldsTextProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` , the binding should no longer be part of my DataContext object? `FieldsTextProperty` exists in my `MainViewModel`.

Comment: @MikaelKP That would work providing the control's `DataContext` contains a property called `MainViewModel`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your User Control can have a DataContext and any control within that user control can have a different DataContext as well but in your scenario that's not what you should be doing.

Your TextBox should use a simple command bound to the underlying ViewModel of the UserControl and when the command is executed you should use the message bus to get whatever you need from your MainViewModel or any other ViewModel. The message bus is how ViewModels are supposed to communicate and exchange information in MVVM...

Comment: Can you please give an example? I do not quite understand your explanation. This is how I understand it: I should change the TextBox logic to something like `<TextBox x:Name="txtMethods" Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding MethodsTextProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="#FFCBEECD" AcceptsReturn="False">
                    <TextBox.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding AddMethodCommand}"></KeyBinding>
                    </TextBox.InputBindings>
                </TextBox>` ?

Comment: Just use that existing command on your TextBox and in the method called by that command use the messaging to get whatever you need from your MainViewModel... Just search for "MVVM Light Messaging" and you'll find plenty of examples... e.g. http://chriskoenig.net/2010/07/05/mvvm-light-messaging/